# Out of memory when starting process from c# and mono

Tags: c#, linux, process, mono, gpio

I am working with an embedded linux board (Atmel AT91SAM) with Debian installed. There is a mono application running and its switching an output from GPIO on/off periodicly (like every 500ms) by calling  *cat* by starting a new System Process with bash. After some time I get an "*Out of memory*" exception and output is not set for a time, after it "recovers itself" after some seconds.

- Is this a bad idea to set the pioC10 this way? If so, how else should
  I set the value file?
- Could this memory exception occur, because of
  not being able to access the GPIO at the moment?
- Is there a clean way to dispose the process, or is it done when method is closed automatically?

  ```
  private void OnTimer1Event(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
  {
          alternateBlinkTimer1.Stop();
          alternateBlinkTimer2.Start();
      try
      {
          var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo { FileName = "/bin/bash", Arguments = "-c \"echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/pioC10/value\"" };
          System.Diagnostics.Process process = new Process();
          process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
          process.Start();
      }
      catch (Exception err)
      {
          log.Error(err.Message);
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try skipping the Process Class and any memory management/garbage collection associated to it by directly use libc's `system`.

In your Class that you are defining the `OnTimer1Event` method, add a definition to `system`:

```
   [DllImport ("libc")]
   private static extern int system (string exec);
```

Then you can:

```
private void OnTimer1Event(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
        alternateBlinkTimer1.Stop();
        alternateBlinkTimer2.Start();
        system("echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/pioC10/value\");
}
```

Comment: Thx! Can you please tell me, whats the difference in view of garbage collection and memory usage?
I will have a try right now!

Comment: In an highly limited memory environment like yours, any time you `new` a class and that object goes out of scope, the GC can reclaim the memory, but only does so when certain thresholds are met. In a restricted memory and cpu env. you should look at using object pools and not creating new objects on each method call. I.e. in your original code, you could move the object creation of `ProcessStartInfo` and `Process` to private members of your class and just call Process.Start each time your timer event is called... so no new objects are created, just re-use existing ones.

Comment: A very good read : SGen GC in Mono : http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/garbage-collector/sgen/

Comment: Thank you for your help! Should I use System.Diagnostics.Process or system from external dll libc now? I have tried your solution and it works. I still need to test it on long run and I will report you the result here.

Comment: Glad it worked, hopefully your long term tests will work out well..  As for which method, that is really up to you, the `system` call is the most direct and has the smallest memory overhead during execution...

Comment: Hello, I cant say for sure, but it the excpetions didnt occur anymore. I will use you static library call, thats why I mark this answer as correct.
Thank you again very much for your help!